# Meteor custom login procedure

Tags: meteor

This Meteor app has the insecure and autopublish removed and accounts-ui accounts-password added.
The code below needs to get the `username` and `password`, send them the to server which will run a method `validateUser` that returns true if valid.
`validateUser` tries to login to another server on the web, and returns true if successful, then my code should create a user account for this user.

The app is crashing because of this line
`Accounts.createUser(useername: digest[0], password: digest[1]);`
But even if it does not, Is this the meteor way to get this particular task done? Thanks

**Edit:**

After adding {} to the problem line in order to pass an object as suggested in the comments, I now get this error printed in the terminal;

> Exception while invoking method 'logMeIn' Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation in field password

```
<template name="myLogin">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="text" name="password">
  <button id="logMe">log me in</button>
</template>

Template.myLogin.events({
 'click #logMe': function() {
  var credentials = [$('#password').val(), $('#username').val()];
   Meteor.call('logMeIn', credentials, function(err, result) {
     if (result) {
       console.log('logged in!');
     }
   });
 }
});

// on the server
Meteor.methods({
  logMeIn: function(credenticals) {
    //do work , if logged in, do next line
    console.log("user account created");
    Accounts.createUser({useername: credenticals[0], password: credenticals[1]});
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesnt the createuser function expect an object {}? So something like {username: credentials[0],pasword: credentials[1]}

Comment: Fixed it as per your suggestion. please see updated error. The password is plain text. I read about Package.sha.SHA256 but it is deprecated.

Comment: Just to make sure: have you noticed your typo in the username? You typed 'useername'

Comment: Thanks, I now get this error: Exception while invoking method 'logMeIn' Error: Match error: Expected string, got object in field username

Comment: i recommemd looking at the console log values of your credentials array and go from there. also notice that password is not actually in position 1 in the array. What I would do is build the credentials object straight on the client instead of using an array in between client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match error: Failed Match.OneOf  - is because this method checks if email or username is presented in the object you are passing. You have typo in username and don't have email.

Next thing you are saying, after fixing typo you get `Exception while invoking method 'logMeIn' Error: Match error: Expected string, got object in field username`

This is because you have array with two undefined "members". Look at your jquery selectors. You are trying to select by id `#` but have `inputs` without ids.

Please organise yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

Accounts.createUser({useername: credenticals[0], password: credenticals[1]});

Has two typos, it should be

Accounts.createUser({username: credentials[0], password: credentials[1]});